# Proving W is a subset of V

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to determine if the set of all additive functions ($f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$) is a subspace of $\mathcal{F}(\mathcal{R},\mathcal{R})$.

Step one is to find the zero of the set.  This is where I get confused.  Can I satisfy this by saying $f(x)=0$ is in the set, as it is an additive function?  And if so, does the zero of a function happen when the output is $0$, or does the function have to be $0$ at all points?

Comment: What is your definition of $\mathcal F(\mathcal R,\mathcal R)$?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming $\mathcal F(\mathbb R,\mathbb R)$ is the vector space of all functions $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$.

To show that the set $V$ consisting of all additive functions is a subspace of $ \mathcal F(\Bbb R,\Bbb R)$ we can use the [one-step subspace test](https://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/One-Step_Vector_Subspace_Test).

To do so, let $f,g\in V$ and let $\lambda\in \Bbb R$. Then
\begin{align*}
(f+\lambda\cdot g)(x+y)
&=f(x+y)+\lambda\cdot g(x+y) \\
&=f(x)+f(y)+\lambda\cdot g(x)+\lambda\cdot g(y) \\
&=(f+\lambda\cdot g)(x)+(f+\lambda\cdot g)(y)
\end{align*}
It follows that $f+\lambda\cdot g\in V$.
Hence $V$ is a subspace of $\mathcal F(\Bbb R,\Bbb R)$.